# Aligning atoms with arrows in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am writing a reaction scheme and tried to use Clemens recommendation
([aligment...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330070/alignment-of-chemfig-molecules-in-a-reaction)) i.e. "starting with the right atom", but I did not succeed to get what I wanted.

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\setarrowdefault{0,1.5,black,thick}
\setdoublesep{0.35700 em}  % 'Bond Spacing'
\setatomsep{1.78500 em}    % 'Fixed Length'
\setbondoffset{0.18265 em} % 'Margin Width'
\newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em} % 'Line Width'
\setbondstyle{line width = \bondwidth}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig{
            (-[:90]OH)-[:-30](-[:-90]OH)-[:30](-[:-30]H)=[:90]O}%
        }{\large{D,L-Glyceraldehyde}}
  \arrow{<<->[aldolase]}
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig{
            (-[:-150]H)(-[:-30]H)=[:90]O}%
        }{\large{Formaldehyde}}
    \+
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig{
            (-[:-90]OH)-[:30](-[:-30]H)=[:90]O}%
    }{\large{Glycolaldehyde}}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the top carbon atoms aligned vertically with the arrow and the '+' sign also, but with this code this is not the case although I took care to start with them.
The following picture shows what I would like to get:

[image]

Comment: if possible, could you also show what you desire your output to be (if possible, in a form of a picture)?

Comment: @Raaja, I added a picture.

Comment: does `\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<<->[aldolase]}` work?

Comment: @Troy, yes, but only for clyceraldehyde and formaldehyde,  The plus sign and glycoladehyde remaining above the line.

Comment: @DRi I just tested, this is my output: https://imgur.com/a/7MK2jJ2. The plus sign looks aligned with the arrow to me. For Glycolaldehyde, you need to start with the aldehyde carbon. Right now you're starting with the alcohol-side carbon

Comment: off-topic: `\large` does not take an argument. Remove the braces, so it should be `\large word`. Also, the individual `\set...` commands from chemfig are deprecated since v1.3. Use `\setchemfig{key=value}` syntax instead.

Comment: @Troy, Thanks a lot, indeed the plus sign is OK (I don't know why it seemed above for my first try of your solution). And yes, i missed it the glycoladehyde should start with the carbonyl carbon. I suppose you can turn your comment into an answer;

Comment: @DRi There are some improvements to your code that I would like to suggest in my answer as well, but I don't have the time to write a full one right now (hence the quick comments). I will do so in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing to do is to set the anchor points that the arrow connects to (visible with `scheme debug` on.) with `\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<<->[aldolase]}`.

Other notes:

- `\setchemfig` and the key-value syntax should be used instead starting from chemfig version 1.3 onwards. The individual `\set...` commands are deprecated.
- For the last molecule, to achieve what you want, you should start drawing the aldehyde carbon first (instead of the alcohol carbon).
- I added a little spacing around the `\+` to fix the overlapping of chemnames.
- `\large` does *not* take an argument, do remove the braces after it.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em} % 'Line Width'
\setchemfig{
    scheme debug = true,
    double bond sep = 0.35700 em,
    atom sep = 1.78500 em,
    bond offset = 0.18265 em,
    bond style = {line width=\bondwidth},
    arrow coeff = 1.5,
    arrow style = thick,
}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig{
            (-[:90]OH)-[:-30](-[:-90]OH)-[:30](-[:-30]H)=[:90]O}%
    }{\large D,L-Glyceraldehyde}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<<->[aldolase]}
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig{
            (-[:-150]H)(-[:-30]H)=[:90]O}%
    }{\large Formaldehyde}
    \+{1.2em,1.2em}
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig{%
            (-[:210]-[6]OH)(=[2]O)-[:-30]H}%
    }{\large Glycolaldehyde}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will add your recommendation to the "Chemfig Scheme Golden Rules" ;-)   1) start with the right atom; 2) set the anchor points that the arrow connects to. By the way I am still with version 1.2 but when I will upgrade I will use `\setchemfig`